# Pyinstaller for Microservice architecture to support multiple services to one Executable file

Tags: python, django, microservices, pyinstaller, executable

We are developing an application driven by a microservices architecture. Django as ORM to the Mobile Application and the database. We additionally have about 4 more python micro-services communicating through WebSockets. We are trying to make these 4+1 ( 4 microservices and 1 Django application ) into one executable file.

We are able to make our Django application an executable file separately but not as an integrated architecture. The other 4 microservice files are all pure python code and they communicate using WebSockets as mentioned already. Additionally, we have a caching system by Redis and a data pipeline system by RabbitMq.

Is there a way to integrate them all together to one python executable file using PyInstaller or maybe any other method? Let me know if the question is not clear, I will try to explain better than this.

Comment: The point of microservices is that they're independently deployable, so I'm not sure what the point of bunding multiple services together would be.